# Disconnect the music bot from voice channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have this as my music class to make my bot play music

```
class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.bot.music = lavalink.Client(self.bot.user.id)
        self.bot.music.add_node("localhost", 7000, 'server-utils', 'eu', 'music-node')
        self.bot.add_listener(self.bot.music.voice_update_handler, 'on_socket_response')
        self.bot.music.add_event_hook(self.track_hook)

    @commands.command(name="music")
    async def music(self, ctx, opt, *, arg=None):
        if opt == "join":
            print(f"music join command worked")
            member = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.id == ctx.author.id, ctx.guild.members)
            if member is not None and member.voice is not None:
                vc = member.voice.channel
                player = self.bot.music.player_manager.create(ctx.guild.id, endpoint=str(ctx.guild.region))
                if not player.is_connected:
                    player.store('channel', ctx.guild.id)
                    await self.connect_to(ctx.guild.id, str(vc.id))
        if opt == "play" and arg is not None:
            try:
                player = self.bot.music.player_manager.get(ctx.guild.id)
                query = f'ytsearch:{arg}'
                results = await player.node.get_tracks(query)
                tracks = results['tracks'][0:10]
                i = 0
                query_result = ''
                for track in tracks:
                    i = i + 1
                    query_result = query_result + f'{i}) {track["info"]["title"]}\n'
                embed = discord.Embed()
                embed.description = query_result

                await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)

                def check(m):
                    return m.author.id == ctx.author.id

                reponse = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
                track = tracks[int(reponse.content)-1]

                player.add(requester=ctx.author.id, track=track)
                if not player.is_playing:
                    await player.play()
            except Exception as error:
                print(error)

        if opt == "stop":
            try:
                player = self.bot.music.player_manager.get(ctx.guild.id)
                if player.is_playing:
                    await player.stop()
            except Exception as error:
                print(error)

        if opt == "leave":
            player = self.bot.music.player_manager.get(ctx.guild.id)
            if player.is_playing:
                await player.stop()
            await self.disconnect_from(ctx.guild.id)

    async def track_hook(self, event):
        if isinstance(event, lavalink.events.QueueEndEvent):
            guild_id = int(event.player.guild_id)
            await self.connect_to(guild_id, None)

    async def connect_to(self, guild_id: int, channel_id: int):
        ws = self.bot._connection._get_websocket(guild_id)
        await ws.voice_state(str(guild_id), channel_id)

    async def disconnect_from(self, guild_id: int):
        ws = self.bot._connection.voice_clients
        print(ws)



def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
```

Everythink works fine except the part to disconnect from the channel he is connected to... I've tried lots of things and can't figure out how to make it disconnect..
Ps: Here the command doesn't do anything but to print a list where I hoped there would be the bot connect, but it had nothing there

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you're passing the guild id as opposed to the voice channels id, for example.

You're in the guild; Hello World with an ID of 12345
You're in the guilds voice channel of; Hello World voice channel which has an id of 6789.

so you're trying to use the guild.id as opposed to the voice channel id. Does this make sense?

Comment: kinda... wo how do you suggest for me to make it disconnect?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do `await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()`

```py
if opt == "leave":
    player = self.bot.music.player_manager.get(ctx.guild.id)
    if player.is_playing:
        await player.stop()
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
```

Comment: I've already tried this I think, but I'll try again just to make sure and I'll be in touch with you with the results

Comment: Yep, like I thought. When tried to use that I got this error: https://hastebin.com/yunahumuze.sql

Comment: that means the bot is not connected in a vc in the server where the command was invoked

Comment: The problem is that he is connected. He is in the same vc I am in. For some reason he thinks he's not...

Answer (score 0):

I did a disconnect command on my Discord bot using VoiceClient.disconnect(). I got some trouble with it in my first approach because the connect command generated the VoiceClient object, but disconnect command could not use it since it was a local variable on the other command, so i just made it global and it works

```
@commands.command()
async def enter(self, ctx):
    try:
        canal = ctx.author.voice.channel
        global voice_client
        voice_client = await canal.connect()

    except AttributeError:
        await ctx.send("Você precisa estar conectado a um canal de voz")

    except discord.errors.ClientException:
        await ctx.send("Eu já estou conectado ao seu canal de voz")

@commands.command()
async def leave(self, ctx):
    try:
        await voice_client.disconnect()

    except NameError:
        await ctx.send("Eu não estou conectado a nenhum canal de voz :worried:")
```

The full music cog that I coded:
https://github.com/Voz-bonita/Discord-Bot/blob/master/Music%20extension.py